# ipython 7.19.0 Crash

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Hello I update my python from **python 3.8.3** to **python 3.9.1** and **reinstall** my library and packages by pip freeze > req and pip install req Of course, I updated some of the packages during installation and I installed the **latest version** of it Not the previous version like **ipython**.
but Now I have problem in using **ipython**

It does not work at all, it does not give suggestions, it can not run a simple Python line **if I press Tab For give Suggestion :/ (Very strange)**, and it does not have autocomplete.

here I run it in CMD And I wrote a simple code to execute :

[image: something]

[image: something]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same problem. The issue is with jedi, you'll need to downgrade from the newest 0.18.0 to the previous 0.17.2:

```
conda install jedi=0.17.2
```

Comment: I test it now Do you think I have to reinstall ipython?

Comment: Yes its Best Answer, ipython works perfectly and flawlessly ;)

Comment: worked for me on MacOS Catalina, Python 3.9. `pip install jedi==0.17.2`, restarted ipython, fixed.